# Export Excel Data to Nested JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, excel, vba

I export data out of Excel into a standard JSON format using the JsonConverter VBA module. The JSON output is similar to below:-

```js
[{
    "Manufacturer": "Ford",
    "Code": 5551234,
    "Model": "Escort"
    "Status": "Available"
  },
  {
    "Manufacturer": "Ford",
    "Code": 5551335,
    "Model": "Mondeo"
    "Status": "Out of stock"
  },
  {
    "Manufacturer": "Ford",
    "Code": 5551240,
    "Model": "Fiesta"
    "Status": "Available"
  },
  {
    "Manufacturer": "BMW",
    "Code": 5552567,
    "Model": "M1"
    "Status": "Available"
  },
  {
    "Manufacturer": "BMW",
    "Code": 5552328,
    "Model": "M2"
    "Status": "Available"
  },
  {
    "Manufacturer": "BMW",
    "Code": 5552573,
    "Model": "M3"
    "Status": "Out of stock"
  }
]
```

The VBA code I am using is as follows:-

```vba
Sub Excel2JSON()

Dim excelRange As Range
Dim jsonItems As New Collection
Dim jsonDictionary As New Dictionary
Dim jsonFileObject As New FileSystemObject
Dim jsonFileExport As TextStream
Dim i As Long
Dim cell As Variant

Set excelRange = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

For i = 2 To excelRange.Rows.Count
    jsonDictionary("Manufacturer") = Cells(i, 1)
    jsonDictionary("Code") = Cells(i, 2)
    jsonDictionary("Model") = Cells(i, 3)
    jsonDictionary("Status") = Cells(i, 4)

    jsonItems.Add jsonDictionary
    Set jsonDictionary = Nothing
Next i

Set jsonFileExport = jsonFileObject.CreateTextFile(".../cardata.json", True)
jsonFileExport.WriteLine (JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(jsonItems, Whitespace:=3))

End Sub
```

I then import that JSON into a HTML table using the following script:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "cardata.json",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      var $tbody = $("table#data tbody");
      $.each(data, function(i, data) {
        var $tr = $("<tr></tr>");
        $tr.appendTo($tbody);
        var $td = $("<td></td>");
        $td.html(data.Manufacturer)
          .appendTo($tr);
        $td = $("<td></td>");
        $td.html(data.Code)
          .appendTo($tr);
        $td = $("<td></td>");
        $td.html(data.Model)
          .appendTo($tr);
        $td = $("<td></td>");
        $td.html(data.Status)
          .appendTo($tr);
      });
    },
  });
});
```

The question/issue is two-fold. I want to import the JSON into 2 different HTML tables rather than one (one table for Ford, the other for BMW etc). I know the JSON below will work with 2 different tables, however I am unable to amend the VBA code to create a JSON which looks like below:-

```js
{
  "Ford": [{
      "Code": 5551234,
      "Model": "Escort"
      "Status": "Available"
    },
    {
      "Code": 5551335,
      "Model": "Mondeo",
      "Status": "Out of stock"
    },
    {
      "Code": 5551240,
      "Model": "Fiesta",
      "Status": "Available"
    }
  ],
  "BMW": [{
      "Code": 5552567,
      "Model": "M1",
      "Status": "Available"
    },
    {
      "Code": 5552328,
      "Model": "M2",
      "Status": "Available"
    },
    {
      "Code": 5552573,
      "Model": "M3",
      "Status": "Out of stock"
    }
  ]
}
```

The alternative is keeping the JSON the same, but changing the way the script imports it into 2 different HTML tables.

Comment: I suppose I should add - I know one solution would be to create a separate JSON for each manufacturer, but that would result in over 20 different JSON files. If I can keep it to one file, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below I have changed your JSON using jQuery in the format you want.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $.ajax({
          url: "cardata.json",
          method: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data){
            var manufacturers = {};

            data.forEach(function(element) {

               if(!manufacturers[element.Manufacturer])
                   manufacturers[element.Manufacturer] = new Array();

                   var obj = {};
                   obj.Code = element.Code;
                   obj.Model = element.Model;
                   obj.Status = element.Status;
                   manufacturers[element.Manufacturer].push(obj);
            });


           console.log(manufacturers); //As object
           console.log(JSON.stringify(manufacturers)); // In JSON

          }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Although I'm getting errors on lines 10 through 13. Is there any way for this to append to defined tables in HTML? I.E id="bmw" and id="ford" etc.

Comment: Dreamweaver comes up with syntax error on line 10 &12. Although it doesn't elaborate on what the exact error is.

Comment: I have changed some syntax at line 10. May this works.

Comment: Many thanks, this works. I can see the data in the console log. How would I append this to existing tables in the HTML page? I have a few tables identified by the manufacturer. I.E id="bmw", id="ford" etc.

Comment: Thanks Ash, I sussed it. I'll add the working code below. Your help was much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using code provided by Ash, the tables now populate correctly. It's possible I've appended the data the long way round, but it's working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "cardata.txt",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            var vendors = {};

            data.forEach(function(element) {

                if (!manufacturers[element.Manufacturer])
                    manufacturers[element.Manufacturer] = new Array();

                var obj = {};
                obj.Code = element.Code;
                obj.Model = element.Model;
                obj.Status = element.Status;
                manufacturers[element.Manufacturer].push(obj);
            });

            var $tbody = $("table#BMW tbody");
            $.each(manufacturers.BMW, function(i, data) {
                var $tr = $("<tr></tr>");
                $tr.appendTo($tbody);
                var $td = $("<td></td>");
                $td.html(data.Code)
                    .appendTo($tr);
                $td = $("<td></td>");
                $td.html(data.Model)
                    .appendTo($tr);
                $td = $("<td></td>");
                $td.html(data.Status)
                    .appendTo($tr);
            });

            var $tbody = $("table#Ford tbody");
            $.each(manufacturers.Ford, function(i, data) {
                var $tr = $("<tr></tr>");
                $tr.appendTo($tbody);
                var $td = $("<td></td>");
                $td.html(data.Code)
                    .appendTo($tr);
                $td = $("<td></td>");
                $td.html(data.Model)
                    .appendTo($tr);
                $td = $("<td></td>");
                $td.html(data.Status)
                    .appendTo($tr);
            });

            console.log(manufacturers); //As object
            console.log(JSON.stringify(manufacturers)); // In JSON

        }
    });
});
```